# SCSS/CSS background-image url path problem

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an SCSS project and I need to use background-image property on a div, but it doesn't find the image. (CSS is properly linked). This is my SCSS code:

```
.coffee-icon {
    background-image: url('./../img/coffee.png') no-repeat;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

and this is the folder structure:

[image: project folder structure]

Some notes at the end: it doesn't work with "", or without quotes, and I'm pretty sure it is a problem with path, I just don't know what it is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a perfect world your URL paths should be absolute, so always starting with / refering to the base path of the domain.

You have:

> ```
> background-image: url('./../img/coffee.png') no-repeat;
> ```

The shape you should be looking for is:

```
 background-image: url('/folder/img/coffee.png') no-repeat;
                        ^ This lead slash references the base path of the domain.
```

So, the above example is `domain.com/folder/img/coffee.png` - you see the leading `/` is the base the whole URL is based from.

The advantage of this is your SCSS or CSS or image files can be placed in any location in your domain structure.

## Absolute Pathing is the key to success!

**Example 2:**

```
 background-image: url('/images/tea.png') no-repeat;
```

Image is located at:

```
 mydomain.org/images/tea.png
```

The location of the SCSS or CSS file is not important, as long as it's on the same domain.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

If other alternatives don't work, you can use `~` to reference the project directory and access `public` folder from there.

```
background-image: url("~/public/images/icon.png");
```

**OR** the other alternative would be to move images to the `src` directory, and this won't be a problem since webpack would pack them in a folder called `static/media` as static files

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just figured it out, just for somebody else in the future I used /img/blabla.png
which apparently sets it to start from root directory.

Comment: hah, yep. My somewhat more verbose answer states this `:-)`